# How do I remove a css class from a jQuery object using a wildcard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Environment is jQuery v3.6.0 and Bootstrap 5.1.3.

I have one or more phone number fields. I use Bootstrap to display an input group prepended to each field. That input group contains a a national flag image. That flag image is supposed to dynamically change according to the country the user has selected in another field.

The span displaying the flag has two classes: the flag class and a country-specific class. Each country-specific class corresponds to a given flag sprite rule within my CSS. Each such rule begins with "country_" and ends with the ISO-3166 country code for the country (e.g., country_us = USA, country_de = Germany, country_fr = France, etc.)

To make this work, I need to be able to remove only the country-specific class using a wildcard so my code does not have to keep track of what the current flag rule is.

jQuery's removeClass() allows me to remove one or more specific classes (e.g., country_us, etc.), but there is *nothing* I've found in the documentation addressing how to target a class using any kind of wildcard or regEx as a selector.

Here is the standard HTML for one of my phone fields:

```
<div id="phone_group" class="form-group">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone Number*</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="flag country_us">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a known-good regEx expression for the class selection, if a regEx is required:

```
/^country_\S+/g
```

Here is my JS function to perform the flag swap:

```
const setFlagIcon = function( countryID ) {
    $( '.flag' ).removeClass( 'what I am asking for goes here?' );
    $( '.flag' ).addClass( 'country_' + countryID );
}
```

And finally, the event handler which triggers it:

```
$( '#country' ).change( function() {        // when user changes the country            
    lookupCountry( $( '#country' ).val() ); // AJAX call to get the countryID (a global var)
    setFlagIcon( countryID );               // change the flag image
});
```

Comment: is `country_<code>` the only class for this element?  If so, you can remove all classes and add the new one

Comment: There are 2 classes: flag and country_<code>. I could conceivably remove/replace both but the wildcard issue remains. I really don't want to have to keep track of the country-specific class. How do I remove both without enumerating each of them?

Comment: any reason you don't want to keep track of the country-specific class? It seems like the simplest solution; unless you want to make it more complex for no particular reason

Comment: I added a second option to my answer that avoids keeping track of the country-specific class

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep track of the current flag id to remove it when the global selector changes value.

See code below for example:

**NOTE**: I mimicked the `lookupCountry(...)` function to serve for the example below - you should use your own function instead

```js
$(function() {
  const setFlagIcon = function(oldClass, newClass) {
    $('.flag').removeClass(oldClass);
    $('.flag').addClass(newClass);
    console.log($('.flag').attr('class'));
  }
  var currentId = 'us'; // keep track of current flag class being used.

  $('#phone').on('change', function() {
    var oldId = currentId;
    var newId = lookupCountry($(this).val());
    console.log(`changed to ${newId}`);
    setFlagIcon('country_' + oldId, 'country_' + newId);
    currentId = newId;
  });

  const lookupCountry = function(id) {
    switch (id) {
      case '1':
        return 'us';

      case '2':
        return 'fr';
      case '3':
        return 'ca';

      default:
        return 'us';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="phone_group" class="form-group">
  <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone Number*</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="flag country_us">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
After reading the comments from OP, another option could be removing all classes and re-adding them (to avoid keeping track of current flag being used)

See option 2 below:

```js
$(function() {
  const setFlagIcon = function(newClass) {
    // change element's class names (remove all)
    var element = $('.flag').removeClass(function() {
      return $(this).attr("class");
    });

    // now add all classes to same element
    $(element).addClass('flag ' + newClass);
    console.log($('.flag').attr('class'));
  }


  $('#phone').on('change', function() {
    var newId = lookupCountry($(this).val());
    setFlagIcon('country_' + newId);

  });

  const lookupCountry = function(id) {
    switch (id) {
      case '1':
        return 'us';

      case '2':
        return 'fr';
      case '3':
        return 'ca';

      default:
        return 'us';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="phone_group" class="form-group">
  <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone Number*</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="flag country_us">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
```